# How to use Zynq to program STM32 MCU?

Tags: stm32, fpga, programming, zynq

I have a custom Zynq board. I need to use this board to program the STM32.
The binary of STM32 will be stored on the Zynq board. How can this be done?
I am assuming jtag/swd but not sure how to do it.

Comment: doesn't the STM32 contain a bootloader from factory?

Comment: There’s an open source cmsis-dap project that you could port to your hardware. It only needs a couple of gpio, so no fgpa resources needed.

Comment: You need to know which exact STM32 model it is, to know the list of available methods for firmware programming, and select which is easiest for you to implement on Zync.